# Is there a Javascript to apk compiler / interpreter that can be run on a server?

Tags: java, javascript, android, compiler-construction

Does anyone know of a Javascript compiler or interpreter (likely to be a mix of both) that can run be on a server?

I am looking to send it my javascript/css/html and have it return a functioning .apk file.

If this is not possible or does not exist is there perhaps a javascript to java and then a java to apk compiler I could implement?

Comment: What, precisely, do you expect this "functioning .apk file" to do?

Comment: @CommonsWare That would depend on the data I have given it. Surely there would be some kind of API. I would want to be able to access things like the camera .etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am still not clear on what you are expecting, but you may want to check out [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/). It takes HTML, CSS, and JS and creates APK files that display that HTML, CSS, and JS.

Comment: Thanks that looks useful, but considering how it runs I'm guessing it would have some serious performance issues.

Comment: I thought about it more and came up with this question... I know it's not exactly what I was asking here but I think it is less vague: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817408/using-javascript-and-php-to-develop-native-android-apps

Answer (score 0):

http://www.onx.ms

May be is good solution for you