# Using javascript and PHP to develop native android apps

Tags: java, php, javascript, android

First off, I apologise for the ambiguity of this question but it is something I am hoping you can clear up for me.

The concept is that I would have a predefined template written in Java for an app, the template would consist of Classes such as:

```
public class Image {  

    private int _x;  
    private int _y;

    Image() {  
        _x = 0;  
        _y = 0;  
    }  

    Image(Int x, Int y) {  
        _x = x;  
        _y = y;  
    }  
}
```

The next bit I understand how to accomplish which is using javascript to post data to PHP, but I then want PHP to use this data to build the Java app. E.g. I might have a PHP function `createImage($x = 0, $y = 0)`, which would then add to the Java source (The PHP would have to pass variable names.etc):

```
Image image342 = new Image(x, y);
```

Which I will later want to compile to an .apk android application.

I am having trouble working out how to get PHP to modify and add to the Java source, I realise I could do this with strings and writing to a physical file .e.g

```
public function createImage ($x = 0, $y = 0) {
  $this->$num++;
  $string = "Image image{$this->$num} = new Image({$x}, {$y});";
  $handle = fopen("/java/source/file", "ab");
  fwrite($handle, $string);
  fclose($handle);
}
```

But this feels somewhat messy, and I'm wondering if there is a better way to achieve my task.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that the entire Android build chain (e.g., compiler, `dx` bytecode cross-compiler) needs files, you have no choice but to create files. Creating a project's worth of customized files based on templates is a fairly typical form of code generation. For example, when you create a new Android project from the Eclipse wizard, that's pretty much what it does.

Part of that code generation would be to create an Ant build script for the Android project (based on the one you get from the `android create project` command). Your server could then code-gen then project and fork a process to run Ant to give you the APK.

Whether PHP is the right solution for your code-generation problem versus using something else that already does template-driven generation of a directory's worth of files, I can't say.